# Is it possible to read html page content and grab a <div> with specific class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing

I am using Nodejs application to read a large web page. The content of this web page are read using REST api call. Once I get the content I am only interested in specific div and everything under that .
I am wondering if there are any nodejs libraries and inbuilt javascript capabilities I can use to make this process seamless.

DOM tree looks like as follows and, I would like to read href Display me. where outermost / parent DIV is with class="three-equal".

```html
<div class="three-equal" data-layout="three-equal">
  <div class="cell normal" data-type="normal">
    <div class="innerCell">
      <p>
        <span </span>
      </p>
      <div class="panel" ">
        <div </div>
          <div class="panelContent " style="background-color: #ffffff; ">

          </div>
        </div>
        <p>
          <span </span>
        </p>
        <div class="panel " </div>
          <div class="panelContent " style="background-color: #ffffff; ">
            <p>
              <em>
                                                                                                        <a href="/display/reference/ ">Display me</a>
                                                                                                    </em>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have invalid html please fix the formatting.

Comment: So why not just use their rest api calls that is generating that data?

Comment: your HTML and attributes are invalid. I tried to format it for you but you need to fix the missing > and the too many "

Comment: You are going to want something like PhantomJS.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

I would use this DOM traversal / manipulation library.
https://github.com/defunctzombie/dom

Read about it's usage here: https://github.com/defunctzombie/dom/wiki